# dtype=np.int32 или dtype=int. Есть ли разница, если есть то в чем?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Есть ли разница, если есть то в чем ? Это библиотека NumPy
При создании массива есть ли разница в dtype=np.int32 или dtype=int. Если есть ,то в чем?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Различие в том, что при использовании `dtype=int`, вместо `int` будет использовано `np.int_`, что в свою очередь представляет собой тип данных `C long`. В зависимости от платформы `np.int_` равен `np.int32` или   `np.int64` (см. пример ниже). Если указать `dtype=np.int32` или `dtype="int32"`, то будет использоваться тип данных `int32` вне зависимости от платформы.

Пример:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=int)
b = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int32)
c = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int_)
print("int: {}".format(a.dtype))
print("int32: {}".format(b.dtype))
print("int_: {}".format(c.dtype))
```

---

Вывод на Windows 64-bit:

```
int: int32
int32: int32
int_: int32
```

Вывод на Linux 64-bit:

```
int: int64
int32: int32
int_: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Основное различие в том, что `int` не фиксированного размера в отличие от `np.int32`. Другое различие в том, что `np.int32` поддерживает больше аттрибутов, относящихся к библиотеке `numpy`.

Comment: вы можете подтвердить ваш ответ примерами? У меня не получилось подтвердить ни одно из этих утверждений

Comment: @MaxU зачем примеры, когда есть документация? https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric

Comment: @MaxU *Since many of these have platform-dependent definitions, a set of fixed-size aliases are provided* vs  *Integers have unlimited precision*

Comment: @MaxU а для второго достаточно заметить тот же аттрибут `size`, которого нет у простого `int` https://repl.it/repls/ModestAcidicAutomaticparallelization

Comment: Вопрос был не о переменной типа “int”, а о Numpy массиве, созданном с параметром “np.array(..., dtype=int)”